# Recursive function to calculate totals from bottom up in array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => Books
            [total_links] => 3
            [subcategories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [title] => Jeffrey Archer
                            [total_links] => 1
                            [subcategories] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                            [title] => Political
                                            [total_links] => 2
                                            [subcategories] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9
                                            [title] => Thriller
                                            [total_links] => 5
                                            [subcategories] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

I need a recursive function that will loop through the `subcategories` from bottom up, adding the `total_links` together and changing the value of the `total_links` in the array above it.

So in the end the array will have `total_links` values of:

- Books = 11
- Jeffrey Archer = 8
- Political = 2
- Thriller = 5

And preferably without the use of the SPL functions (but if there is no other way then feel free).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: I have trouble understanding the logic of your data structure. Are the `total_links` in "Books" *separate* from the `total_links` in the child arrays?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but should do the trick

```
function do_sums(&$array) {
    if (is_array($array['subcategories'])) {
        foreach ($array['subcategories'] as $category_array) {
            $array['total_links'] += do_sums($category_array); // recurse down first
        }
    }
    return($array['total_links']);
}

$your_array = array(...)

do_sums($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code: ([Demo with extended sample data for testing](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a38b927f2daae04facb2215e99c9825d68b8336))

```
function sum_links(&$array){ // make $array modifiable by reference
    foreach($array as &$item){ // make $item modifiable by reference
        if(!empty($item['subcategories'])){  // only recurse if there are children in subcategories
            $item['total_links']+=array_sum(array_column(sum_links($item['subcategories']),'total_links'));
            // recursion returns full subarray, extract desired column data, add sum to the original value
        }
    }
    return $array;  // return the full & updated array
}

var_export(sum_links($array));

/* or because $array is modified by reference...
    sum_links($array);
    var_export($array);
*/
```